# Is it possible to run selenium scripts using google compute engine?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-compute-engine

I would like to run my selenium scripts on the cloud/online/remotely. I have been advised google compute engine could allow this.

It would be appreciated if this could be confirmed and additional steps that will be needed to be given too.

Any other solutions suggested would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference is that your GCE instance doesn't have a display, which is going to be an issue for your browser.

To address this, you'll want to run Selenium using a "Virtual Framebuffer". This is basically a "Fake display".

Here's how you set a Virtual Framebuffer up in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
```

Then, before starting your selenium script, just run:

```
export DISPLAY=:10
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Could you please provide more information how I could run selenium on google compute engine? I am trying to find something online but finding it hard to locate any resources. Is there any search terms you could recommend or websites where I can find what I am looking for? I am a beginner on google compute engine and would appreciate the help

Comment: @user2985043 To be fair, there really isn't anything different between selenium and selenium on GCE. The only difference is the need for a virtual display (see the answer). If you need a detailed walkthrough, you can search for "Selenium Amazon EC2". Using Selenium on GCE should be very similar to EC2.